# State showing different values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I am receiving messages according to the statusuc state when state is active it should receive message or when it is inactive it should not update the array .

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(statusc)
}, [statusc])
const handleJobReceived = (userdata) => {
console.log("The status of a person is " + statusc);

setJobData((prevState) => {
  if (statusc === "Active") {
    console.log("adding function run");
    return [...prevState, userdata];
  } else if (statusc === "Inactive") {
    return [...prevState];
  }
});
};


socket.on("job received", (userdata) => {
console.log("The status of a person is " + statusc);

handleJobReceived(userdata)
});
```

in this code i have also setup a useeffect which shows the value of statusc after changing in the same component i have assigned a button to log the value of statusc on clicking.

```
<button onClick={()=>{console.log(statusc)}}>Current statusc</button>
```

so the problem is that when statusc is changed and console in useffect shows active . and also on clicking button shows Active but console in socket shows inactive or simply the previous stage.

the console looks like
[image]

but where null is initial state of statusuc

Comment: You have a stałe closure

Comment: How to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Put the `socket.on()` code in `useEffect` hook, and add the `statusc` state as the dependency of it. Then you will get the latest `statusc` state instead of the stale one.

E.g.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PubSub from 'pubsub-js';

// simulate socket.emit
setInterval(() => {
  PubSub.publish('job received');
}, 5000);

export default function App() {
  const [statusc, setStatusc] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(statusc);
  }, [statusc]);

  const handleJobReceived = () => {
    console.log('The status of a person is ' + statusc);
    setStatusc(statusc === 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active');
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // simulate socket.on
    const token = PubSub.subscribe('job received', () => {
      console.log('[Socket] The status of a person is ' + statusc);
    });
    return () => {
      PubSub.unsubscribe(token);
    };
  }, [statusc]);

  return <button onClick={handleJobReceived}>change status</button>;
}
```

Click the button after several seconds, the logs:

```
null
null
[Socket] The status of a person is null
[Socket] The status of a person is null
The status of a person is null
active
[Socket] The status of a person is active
[Socket] The status of a person is active
[Socket] The status of a person is active
[Socket] The status of a person is active
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-emlumf?file=src%2FApp.tsx)